# Help setting up my phone or tablet as a hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot, tethering

Can someone help me on how to use my phone or new tablet as a hotspot, so I can connect my old tablet? (using either my phone, or new tablet) I just found my old Tablet, a Galaxy Tab E.  An old guy would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please mention your Android version by [edit] in your question also details of your phone

Answer (score 0):

Options for mobile hotspot/tethering are usually found under ***Wireless & Networks*** section in Settings.

Depending on your target device you may need to navigate to:

*Settings → Wireless & Networks → Personal hotspot (or Tethering & portable hotspot)*

Alternatively, recent versions of Android allow you to search a particular setting that is "hidden" you can use the keyword "hotspot" or "tethering" to get to the required screen, thereafter simply toggle to activate the hotspot (*you may need to configure the hotspot setting first*).

[image]